# Liferay 7 disable features/modules

Tags: liferay, osgi

Liferay 7 is based on OSGi modules.

Therefore... Is it possible to disable some modules/features in order to have a lightweight liferay install. For instance : disable wiki pages or forums...because my project doesn't need this features.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please don't crosspost: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on someone elses post (apparently) but I wanted to add that while both methods work the problem with stopping them in the Gogo shell is that you can't guarantee that they won't start next time the server is restarted. The state of the bundle is dependent on the LIFERAY_HOME/osgi/state folder. There will likely be occasions where you blow this folder away in which case if you have, let's say, previously disabled the Blogs modules, they will no longer have that state recorded and the next time you start they will be active again. Best best, if you are sure

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.
Access to gogo Shell and type the commad: stop $bundleId

Also you can install [Apache Felix Web Console](https://www.dontesta.it/2016/05/05/come-installare-apache-felix-web-console-in-liferay-7/).

[image: Connect to te Apache Felix Gogo Shell]

Comment: How do you access the Gogo Shell?

Comment: You can access via telnet comand, for example: telnet localhost 11311

Answer (score 2):

You just have to delete jar files related  to portlet you want to disable/remove from osgi/modules folder.

You can install those feature back just by copying jar files to modules folder later.

Refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPjmB5yj8Og from Dev.life sessions.

Comment: But... what are the equivalences beetween modules(jar) and features? I want to know what features I will loose when I delete a jar from modules folder.... For instance : I don't need forums... but probably I want the comments features for JournalArticles....

Comment: @moisesbelda that sounds like a new question... You're asking "is it possible" and the answer is "yes". Now you give *one* example where you're asking for specific dependencies... How could anyone know what other dependencies you're asking for? You can always remove or stop some bundle (check gogo shell) and check what other features were dependent on it (thus automatically deactivated). I'd suggest to accept this answer and experiment by yourself or ask a *specific* separate question.

Comment: I have deployed a Liferay 7 CE GA3 instance.  I don't see the Jar files to which you are refering.  I see only LPKG files.  Where in the folder structure would you find the Jar files you are mentioning.